# Why are my Pythons and pip in different places?

Tags: python, pip

I am using Mac OSX. I was having so many troubles with python environment s I wiped out almost everything I could and fresh installed. But I'm still having so many issues installing stuff.

But first, I want to know if my Python environments are correct.

**Questions**
 1. Do these look okay?
 2. I installed python3 through Homebrew. Is this why python3 is in local/bin not bin?

## My Python environments

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ user1$ which python
/usr/bin/python
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ user1$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ user1$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ user1$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Comment: The default python is located at /usr/bin. Whenever you install python from homebrew, its usually installed in /usr/local/bin. I think, there's nothing to worry. Everything looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Default python and pip in /usr/bin.

Extra installation (coldbrew or whatever) can be in anywhere. As long as they are in path, they'll work.